# Replace a method with parameters by a closure in metaclass

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.2

I have two class:

```
class Foo {
    String doSomething(String a, String b) {
        return 'Not Working'
    }
}


class Bar {
    String methodIWannaTest() {
        return new Foo().doSomething('val1', 'val2')
    }
}
```

And I want to replace 'doSomething' in a test but it dosent work

```
class BarTests {
    @Test
    void testMethodIWannaTest() {
        Foo.metaClass.doSomething {String a, String b -> return 'Working'}

        assert new Bar().methodIWannaTest() == 'Working' //THIS TEST FAIL, return 'Not Working'
    }
}
```

*I know the test doesn't really make sens, it's just to show my point

What do I do wrong ? Is it possible to do it without using 'mockFor' ?

Comment: It works running as a script in Groovy 2.1.3... Maybe something junit related?

Comment: It also works as a Unit Test in Grails 2.2.0.

Comment: @Thermech Which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

First, in my exemple, I forgot the '=' when defining the closure

```
Foo.metaClass.doSomething {String a, String b -> return 'Working'}
```

should be

```
Foo.metaClass.doSomething = {String a, String b -> return 'Working'}
```

While searching I also found that you **cannot replace a method with optionnal parameters** by a closure. Probably a bug

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to start the test afresh. Baby Steps is what I follow. :)

- Create a new grails app.
- Create both `Foo` and `Bar` inside `src/groovy` under a package.
- Create unit test case from command prompt. Put the desired test code.
- Execute `grails test-app`

[Grails v2.2.0]

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use [Groovy MockFor](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+MockFor+and+StubFor).

```
def mock = MockFor(Foo)
mock.demand.doSomething = {String a, String b -> return 'Working'}
mock.use {
  assert new Bar().methodIWannaTest() == 'Working'
}
```

A downside is that there [was a bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8535), making unit tests not clear the mock. This is fixed for 2.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on **GGTS 3.2.0** and got the following results.

Copied all the code and ran on Grails 2.2.2: everything worked correctly. However, then I commented out `Foo.metaClass.doSomething = {String a, String b -> return 'Working'}` line and, surprisingly, the test was still passing successfully. I did more changes and the metaClass just seemed to get "cached" between tests: changes had no effect.

Then I thought if it is possible that Grails were running in interactive mode. Went to **Preferences > Groovy > Grails > Grails Launch** and found a checkbox **'Keep external Grails running'** ticked. Its tooltip even has the following words: 'Warning: experimental feature!'. Unticking that checkbox did the trick and the metaClass no longer got cached between test runs. I am still wondering why an exprimental feature would be turned on by default...